# Return multi columns result from single table with zero values

Tags: mysql, left-join, zero, cross-join

I have a single table like :

```
mysql> select RefID,State,StartTime,EndTime from execReports limit 5;
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| RefID                                | State     | StartTime           | EndTime             |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 00019a52-8480-4431-9ad2-3767c3933627 | Completed | 2016-04-18 13:45:00 | 2016-04-18 13:45:01 |
| 00038a8a-995e-4cb2-a335-cb05d5b3e92d | Aborted   | 2016-05-03 04:00:00 | 2016-05-03 04:00:02 |
| 001013f8-0b86-456f-bd59-a7ef066e565f | Completed | 2016-04-14 03:30:00 | 2016-04-14 03:30:11 |
| 001f8d23-3022-4271-bba0-200494de678a | Failed    | 2016-04-30 05:00:00 | 2016-04-30 05:00:02 |
| 0027ba42-1c37-4e50-a7d6-a4e24056e080 | Completed | 2016-04-18 03:45:00 | 2016-04-18 03:45:02 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I can extract the count of exec for each state with :

```
mysql> select distinct State,count(StartTime) as nbExec from execReports group by State;
+-----------+--------+
| State     | nbExec |
+-----------+--------+
| Aborted   |      3 |
| Completed |  14148 |
| Failed    |     49 |
+-----------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I can extract the count of exec for each week with :

```
mysql> select distinct extract(week from StartTime) as Week, count(StartTime) as nbExec from execReports group by Week;
+------+--------+
| Week | nbExec |
+------+--------+
|   14 |   1317 |
|   15 |   3051 |
|   16 |   3066 |
|   17 |   3059 |
|   18 |   3059 |
|   19 |    652 |
+------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

But I would like to extract a crossing table like :

```
+------+---------+-----------+--------+---------+---------+
| Week | nbExec  | Completed | Failed | Running | Aborted |
+------+---------+-----------+--------+---------+---------+
|   14 |   1317  |   1312    |    3   |    1    |    1    |
|   15 |   3051  |   3050    |    1   |    0    |    0    |
|   16 |   3066  |   3060    |    3   |    2    |    1    |
|   17 |   3059  |   3058    |    0   |    1    |    0    |
|   18 |   3059  |   3057    |    1   |    0    |    1    |
|   19 |    652  |   652     |    0   |    0    |    0    |
+------+---------+-----------+--------+---------+---------+
```

I'm stuck on this for a few days. Any help appreciated.

Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: Note that distinct isn't doing anything here

Answer (score 2):

```
select extract(week from StartTime) as Week, count(StartTime) as nbExec, 
       sum(if(state="Completed",1,0)) Completed,
       sum(if(state="Failed",1,0)) Failed,
       sum(if(state="Aborted",1,0)) Aborted
    from execReports group by Week;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d5bf/12)

Comment: Goods solution. In MySQL: true= 1, false = 0. Hence you can simply write `sum(state='Completed') as Completed`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I started with that but probably was wrong in smthg and returned to more clasic way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can join multi tables for this. If you want for dynamic row to column, check this: [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

```
SELECT 
   a.week, 
   count(a.StartTime) as nbExec,
   count(b1.StartTime) as Completed,
   count(b2.StartTime) as Failed,
   count(b3.StartTime) as Running,
   count(b4.StartTime) as Aborted,

FROM execReports a
LEFT JOIN execReports b1 ON a.refID = b1.refID and b1.state ='Completed'
LEFT JOIN execReports b2 ON a.refID = b2.refID and b2.state ='Failed'
LEFT JOIN execReports b3 ON a.refID = b3.refID and b3.state ='Running'
LEFT JOIN execReports b4 ON a.refID = b4.refID and b4.state ='Aborted'
GROUP BY 1
```